# How can i access my createjs exported js file using a new class in a other javascript file?

Tags: javascript, createjs

How can i make class or a function class in a javascript to access my createjs exported js file?

because i write all my code inside my createjs exported js file...
and it makes my program run slowly..

i dont know how to acces my codes outside my createjs exported js...

```js
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

i always get this error when i try to make a class to access my scripts inside my exported js file from createjs...

help me please.....

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting from Flash CS6?  There is a pretty good tutorial here that uses exported code in combination with outside classes to give you an idea of how it's done:  http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=4454